# Default properties of Java Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

What are the exact default values of two meta annotations (Target and Retention) in a user defined annotation?

```
public @interface AnnotationWithDefaultProps {
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the source code, none of them has a default value, which means you must provide it, whenever you use the annotation. The meaning of the missing annotation is defined in the javadoc:

For `Target` it means

> If a Target meta-annotation is not present on an annotation type declaration, the declared type may be used on any program element.

and for `Retention` it means

> If no Retention annotation is present on an annotation type declaration, the retention policy defaults to RetentionPolicy.CLASS.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, there are no defaults for annotations not specified.  The annotations simply aren't there.

But for these two in particular,

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html says

> If no Retention annotation is present on an annotation type declaration, the retention policy defaults to RetentionPolicy.CLASS.

and equivalently for target,

> If a Target meta-annotation is not present on an annotation type declaration, the declared type may be used on any program element.

Answer (score 1):

Default compiler behavior (if annotation not present)

@Target

> If an @Target meta-annotation is not present on an annotation type T ,
> then an annotation of type T may be written as a modifier for any
> declaration except a type parameter declaration.

parameter declaration is **ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER** (Applies to *parameterized types, generic declarations*)

Java SE 8/11

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Target.html

@Retention

> Indicates how long annotations with the annotated type are to be
> retained. If no Retention annotation is present on an annotation type
> declaration, the retention policy defaults to RetentionPolicy.CLASS.

Java SE 8/11

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html?is-external=true
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html